# Mysql query search based on variable input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-mobile

I am quite new at coding such things as I am asking so I would appreciate if someone could perhaps help me out.

I am looking to do an MYSQL search and echo based on variables selected in a drop-down menu. I am not too sure on how to search 1 inputted variable let alone multiple based on the selected. I would like it to be a filtering system.

Here is my form:

```html
<form>
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
    <legend>Horizontal, mini sized:</legend>
    <label for="select-h-6a">Select A</label>
    <select name="select-h-6a" id="select-h-6a">
        <option value="#">One</option>
        <option value="#">Two</option>
        <option value="#">Three</option>
    </select>
    <label for="select-h-6b">Select B</label>
    <select name="select-h-6b" id="select-h-6b">
        <option value="#">One</option>
        <option value="#">Two</option>
        <option value="#">Three</option>
    </select>
    <label for="select-h-6c">Select C</label>
    <select name="select-h-6c" id="select-h-6c">
        <option value="#">One</option>
        <option value="#">Two</option>
        <option value="#">Three</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

(would I need a submit button to send the query?)

Here is the code I am using to get posts at the moment:

```
$posts = getAllPosts();

<div id="searchpost">
      <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
       <div id="postTitle">

        <?php echo $posts[$p]["post_title"];?></div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-body ui-body-a">
         <div id="postContent">
        <?php echo $posts[$p]["post_content"];}?></div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

and the functions for that:

```
function getAllPosts() {
    require "config.php";
    $posts = $c->query ( "SELECT * FROM posts" );

    if ( $posts->num_rows > 0 ) {

        while( $row = $posts->fetch_assoc() )  {

                $postData[] = array( "user_id" => $row[ "user_id" ], "post_title" => $row[ "post_title" ], "post_content" => $row[ "post_content" ] );
            }
    } else {
        return "No Data";
    }
    return $postData;
}
```

Posting the data:

```
<div id="postTitle">

    <?php echo $posts[$p]["post_title"];?></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-body ui-body-a">
     <div id="postContent">
    <?php echo $posts[$p]["post_content"];}?></div>
  </div>
```

However, as you can see, it calls for things in the database specifically. How can I make what I select in the drop down menus be shown instead of the specifics?

Can this be added for multiple selected options such as selecting rock, singer and 2 members showing only the records that all three of those in it? I assume if I don't want something specific in option 2 I can have an all option which searches for everything in that category.

My database: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op0W9.png)

Connection: (config.php)

```
<?php

    $c = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "user", "pass", "database");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {

        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

    }

?>
```

So, I need help with: 
- putting the drop down options into variables
- having those variables be put into an MYSQL search query

I think the variables are the key here but I am not too sure on how to do it.

I hope you understand what I am needing help with. If not please ask questions :) Thank you so much xx

Comment: By what field do you want to filter your query?

Comment: If you want to make it live (aka not reload the page) then you need to use jQuery and Ajax - Start with something simple to understand the idea. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.webslesson.info/2016/03/ajax-live-data-search-using-jquery-php-mysql.html)

Comment: Hi there, I don't mind reloading the page, in fact, I expected that was what I would have to do. I am trying to search by a dropdown menu like the one in the form code. So if for example, my database is full of music genres I can select rock and search and it will come back with all the entries with rock in the database genre field. I want to be able to do this but with multiple search fields. So like in the form code it has 3 dropdown menus, I want to be able to search with all three of those fields and the results echoing entries that contain only those three selected. :)

Comment: I hope to filter by genre, role and members. So genre will have stuff like rock and pop in the drop downs, role will have the members role such as singer or guitarist and member will be how many members are in the band.

Comment: Learn how to do it with one dropdown and then use multiple: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBxcPOxRgeE

Comment: When you eat an elephant how should you do it? Do you know how to send an HTML form to PHP? Do you know how to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`?